# How can I show that $f$ is uniformly continuous in $X$?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, uniform-continuity

Let $(X,\rho)$ a metric space, and $x_0 \in X$ an arbitrary point.
It defines $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ through:
$$f(x)=\rho(x,x_0).$$
prove that $f$ is uniformly continuous in $X$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint :** Prove that if $\rho$ is a metric, then $|\rho(x,z) - \rho(y,z)| \leq \rho(x,y)$.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* It's actually Lipschitz continuous.